# Nucleo H743 USB OTG FS not enumerating when external 3.3V source is used

Tags: stm32

Scratching my head on this one. I am using a Nucleo H743ZI2 board.

The manual claims it is recommended to use an external power source when using the USB OTG port. Up until now I was using the STLink USB as it was the most convenient when testing things out.

I am getting ready to port the project into the actual system and am using the only available power source, a 3.3V from a shield.

According to the manual (chapter 6.4.5) this is fine:

> When the 3.3 V is provided by a shield board, it is interesting to use the 3V3 (CN8 pin 7 or CN11 pin 16) directly as power input (Refer to Table 9 and Figure 14). In this case, programming and debugging features are not available, since the STLINK-V3E is not powered.

However, this either fails to mention that using a 3.3V source will prevent the USB OTG from enumerating, or I must be missing something obvious.

edit: the datasheet also gives this warning in the USB OTG FS chapter (6.6.6), not sure if it's relevant to the issue though.

> Warning: USB Micro-AB connector (CN13) cannot power the Nucleo-
> 144 board. To avoid damaging the STM32H7, it is mandatory
> to power the Nucleo-144 before connecting a USB cable on
> CN13. Otherwise, there is a risk of current injection on
> STM32H7 I/Os.

Comment: Is the STM32 functioning as the USB host or device?  If as the host, you must be able to supply 5v power on the USB connector to the device.

Comment: thanks for the comment. the STM32 USB OTG is configured as a device.

Comment: Is your software monitoring VBus through PA9 and appropriately activating the enumeration pullup?  Does the host see that something has been plugged in but fail to read the descriptors, or does it not even notice that anything purporting to be a USB device has been connected?  What firm evidence do you have that your MCU firmware is even running?

Comment: I have a couple indications that the H7 is running (I have a couple of debug LED's, and it's correctly communicating with the board supplying the 3.3). Nothing is happening on the computer when the USB is plugged in, no new device is added to the device manager, no chime, etc). I do have Vbus and SOF disabled. The only way I get the device to be recognized is when I also connect the STlink USB which effectively powers the nucleo with 5V from the STlink USB. I haven't tried using a 5V external source, I don't have any 5V source on this system

Comment: First thing to realize is that simply connecting a resistor from D+ to VBus will cause a computer to think a USB device has been plugged in and try to read out its descriptors (or D- for low speed).  So if that isn't happening, the MCU software isn't applying its (in this case apparently internal) pull up resistor, typically because the firmware is not running, wrong, or not managing to monitor the USB VBus.

Comment: I just did a test with a brand new nucleo board (the same though), I powered the nucleo with 3.3 from a lab PSU and tried to connect the USB and no device is detected. Powering that same nucleo board with an USB cable on the STlink, and then connecting the USB OTG allows the computer the see the device. As far as I remember these boards come with a firmware preloaded, not sure.

Comment: Also, I'll add that to the question as a piece of info, but the datasheet for that nucleo board does give this warning in chapter 6.6.6, which is why I always apply power first then connect the USB OTG cable: Warning: USB Micro-AB connector (CN13) cannot power the Nucleo-
144 board. To avoid damaging the STM32H7, it is mandatory
to power the Nucleo-144 before connecting a USB cable on
CN13. Otherwise, there is a risk of current injection on
STM32H7 I/Os.

Comment: Even if the Nucleo came with a firmware, what use would it possibly have?  To accomplish anything meaningful, you need to build a firmware that implements your functionality.  Build that.  Give it debug output on a serial port you can collect with something else.  Take time to make sure it is correctly configuring the enumeration pullup in response to VBus...

Comment: I was only checking to see if there was possibly something with this board. The board used on my project is communicating properly when the board is powered with 5V but somehow when an external 3.3V source is used the board is not detected by the windows machine. And the firmware is running even if the 3.3V source is used.

Comment: Again, you need to investigate the logic which supposedly results in the internal pull-up resistor being applied to D+ or D-.  Literally holding a junk box resistor between one of those terminals and VBus will cause a PC to think something is connected, so if it isn't thinking that, start by figuring out why the internal resistor is not getting connected.  Put debug output in the code which would do so and monitor it via an independent USB-UART...

Comment: I understand the idea you have, I am not sure how to implement considering I need the STlink to debug, but when it's connected there is no problem to investigate. I was more trying to find a way to understand electrically why it works when the STlink USB is connected. I'll do a quick test with an external 5V lab power source (leaving the STlink disconnected) and see if the USB OTG enumerates then.

Comment: As mentioned twice already and now for the third time,  use an outboard USB-UART to capture debug messages you make your code send to an MCU serial UART.  Also simply study the code until you have a clear idea of how the USB detection pull-up is supposedly being activated.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help I'll try to put my hand on that FTDI adapter I have somewhere. And the external 5V gives me no better device detection than with the 3.3 source.